# Contour integration with the contour $\sigma=[0,1]+[1,i]$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

$\sigma=[0,1]+[1,i]$ is a contour. I am asked to sketch the contour, and evaluate $\int_\sigma Re(z)$.

Firstly, I am not sure how to visualise this contour, since there are two parts. What does it look like?

Onto the integral: I know that the formula for integrating a contour $\gamma$ is $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$, where $[a,b]$ is an interval.

In the solutions, the integral has been split into two parts: $\sigma_1(t)=t$ ($0\le t\le1$)  and $\sigma_2(t)=1+(i-1)t$ ($0\le t\le1$). What is the reason for splitting up $\sigma$, and how do we deduce the expressions for $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, as well as the interval $0\le t \le 1$?

From here on, I understand how to obtain the solution: $f(\sigma_1(t))=Re(\sigma_1(t))=t$, and $\sigma'(t)=1$. Hence, $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)=\int_0^1t dt=\frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, $f(\sigma_2(t))=Re(\sigma_2(t))=1-t$, and $\sigma_2'(t)=i-1.$ Hence, $\int_0^1(1-t)(i-1)dt = \frac{i-1}{2}$.

To finish off, $\int_\sigma Re(z)dz = \int_{\sigma_1}Re(z) dz + \int_{\sigma_2}Re(z) dz$ = $\frac{i}{2}$.

So, really, I am only stuck on firstly visualising the contour, and secondly, the intuition behind separating $\sigma$ into $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I presume $[0,1]$ is the line from $0$ to $1$, and $[1,i]$ is the line from $1$ to $i$. Can you draw those?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the statement of your problem, it's not really clear what those two "closed intervals" mean.  After you give the parameterization, it's clearer.

Here is a plot:

[image]

The contour is separated into two parameterizations because it consists of two line segments.